# Board doesn't print properly

Tags: python

I'm supposed to make a connect four console and for some reason my board is displaying 0s instead of "."s. I'm not sure what I did wrong. There are 3 modules, but I'll only show this one since I assume that's where the underlying issue is.

```
import connectfour

def _print_board_num():
    for i in range(len(connectfour.new_game().board)):
        print(str(i+1), end = ' ')
    print()

def print_board(game: 'connectfour.GameState')->[(str)]:
    _print_board_num()
    for row in range(connectfour.BOARD_ROWS):
        for column in range(connectfour.BOARD_COLUMNS):
            if game.board[column][row] == ' ':
                print('.', end = ' ')
            else:
                print(game.board[column][row], end = ' ')

        print()

def move()->str:
    input('Drop or Pop? ')

def column1()->int:
    int(input('What number of column? '))
```

My board is printing like:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

but it's supposed to be printing like :

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
. . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . 
. . . . . . .
```

This is the game board function for the connectfour module

```
def _new_game_board() -> [[int]]:
    '''
    Creates a new game board.  Initially, a game board has the size
    BOARD_COLUMNS x BOARD_ROWS and is comprised only of integers with the
    value NONE
    '''
    board = []

    for col in range(BOARD_COLUMNS):
        board.append([])
        for row in range(BOARD_ROWS):
            board[-1].append(NONE)

    return board



def _copy_game_board(board: [[int]]) -> [[int]]:
    '''Copies the given game board'''
    board_copy = []

    for col in range(BOARD_COLUMNS):
        board_copy.append([])
        for row in range(BOARD_ROWS):
            board_copy[-1].append(board[col][row])
```

I would assume it's either one of these two. Mostly the drop function since I commented out the player error but it shows up for the drop function.

```
def player(game: 'connectfour.GameState') -> None:
    while True:
        player = input('Would you like to drop(d) or pop(p)?')
        if player == 'd':
            drop(game)
            return
        elif player == 'p':
            pop(game)
            return
        else:
            connectfour.InvalidMoveError(Exception)
            #print('Invalid Move')

def drop(game: 'connectfour.GameState') -> bool:
    try:
        col = connectfouroverlap.column1()
        board = connectfour.drop(game,col-1)
        connectfouroverlap.print_board(board)
        if gameover(board) != connectfour.NONE:
            return
        else:
            player(board)
    except:
        connectfour.InvalidMoveError(Exception)
        print('Invalid Move')
```

This is what the output looks like when I run it.

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
. . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . 
Would you like to drop(d) or pop(p)?d
What number of column? 2
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
. . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . 
. 1 . . . . . 
Invalid Move
```

Comment: What is in game.board?

Comment: @vmonteco I dont think that part matters since the connectfour module is premade for us.

Comment: It does because we need to know what you're manipulating to help you.

Comment: @vmonteco I editted in at the end.

Answer (score 3):

After checking your code, I assume that `game.board` is a double array that only contains `0` (integers?) values.

If that's true, try replacing :

```
        if game.board[column][row] == ' ':
            print('.', end = ' ')
        else:
            print(game.board[column][row], end = ' ')
```

with :

```
        if game.board[column][row] == 0:  # <--- change the condition here
            print('.', end = ' ')
        else:
            print(game.board[column][row], end = ' ')
```

**EDIT:** the `->[str]` annotation in your `print_board` function definition suggests that this function is meant to return a string array. But it doesn't.

You're creating a whole new board to print the col numbers. That's a bad practice, use the existing one instead.

You also could use `for in` loops directly on the array rather than using indexes. That would require far less code and would be much clearer and easier to write :

```
for row in game.board:  # <--  since game.board is your [[int]]
    for number in row:
        do_stuff_on(number)
```

Comment: After looking inthe original module some more, I noticed this
NONE = 0
RED = 1
YELLOW = 2

Could that be why?

Comment: @accelerate So it seems I was right about what the board is. Does the solution I suggested work?

Comment: I just did what you did and it replaced the 0s with .s but now it displays it vertically instead of how the board is usually like.

Comment: Oh okay nevermind I fixed it. Thanks! Somehow the print() got tabbed out

Comment: @accelerate I've added some notes, take some time to read and undertand it. Feel free to validate my answer if you considered it solved your problem.

Comment: is it fine to ask you something related to the assignment but not this specific topic?

Comment: Ask, I'll try to answer you.

Comment: I'm sure you know how connect four works. Now when I drop a piece and ask for which column, it drops the piece but it also gives me the invalid move error after. Right after that, the game just exits and doesn't ask the other player to make a move. I'll put the code and the end of my original post.

Comment: @accelerate Make a new post, you didn't provide enough code. Where is the exception raised for instance? I can't help you because you didn't provide enough elements.

Comment: @accelerate But I also would suggest you to study more the language because there are  simple points in your code that may make no sense and I think that could show a lack of basic knowledge. I need more code to be sure though.